# Save AlamofireImage Cache

Tags: ios, caching, swift3, alamofire, alamofireimage

Like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828215/alamofireimage-saved-to-cache-images-are-not-really-saved) I use AlamofireImage to cache Images in my App. But I have not found a way, how to save the cache for the next runtime. I want that after a restart of my app all images are already cached without reloading all Images at the beginning. Is there a simple way to solve this problem?

Comment: for image cache use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @phanisai does SDWebImage save the cache for the next runtime automatically ?

Comment: Yes will cache @iamDeveLoper